# AS3 gotoAndStop not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having a problem with my app. I've 3 frame in the timeline, in the 2nd frame I've a MC with its own class: at the end of the animation of the MC I call a function from the main class.
**THE CODE OF THE MC CLASS IS THIS**

```
public function frame134() {
        stop();

        var vMainTimeline: MainTimeline = new MainTimeline();
        vMainTimeline.gotoFrame3();
    }
```

**THE FUNCTION IN THE MAIN CLASS IS THIS**

```
public function gotoFrame3() {
        trace("gotoFrame3");
        this.gotoAndStop(3);
        trace("DONE");
    }
```

The output in the console is *gotoFrame3* and *DONE* but gotoAndStop(3); doesn't work.
Any suggestion or help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're creating a new instance of MainTimeline. This is bad. Remove those two lines and try something like `MovieClip(root).gotoFrame3();` instead.

Comment: Ok, that worked for me. I used this code var vMainTimeline: MainTimeline = new MainTimeline(); following a guide, so how can I call a public function from another class?

Comment: If you want to call a public method directly, you need to have a reference to the object. The alternative is to use events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather then creating instance of MainTimeline you need to get reference by using `parent` property or by referring it by `stage` directly. Replace your `frame134()` method with below code.

```
public function frame134() {
            var stageRef = this.parent;
            stageRef.gotoAndStop(3);
        }
```

or with

```
public function frame134() {
            stage.gotoAndStop(3)
        }
```

Hope it will work for you.